# getting html attribute value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm uploading files directly to amazon S3. The second input tag is already there on page load, but the first input tag with the values only gets inserted when a file gets uploaded to the S3 bucket.

I would like to get the `id` and the `filename` value from the first input tag with jquery to be able to insert them to a URL path. How can I get those values?

```
<span class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-file">Choose image
  <input value={'id': '55e3385361c84c81c98087907e3f424ff4db6dac412cdcadf40090c04c25',
                'filename': 'firstlogo.png', 
                'content_type':'image/png',
                'size':43393}" 
         data-reference="d105c8c6fd72880c844dc61cb52b0639" 
         type="hidden" 
         name="product[product_image]">
  <input presigned="true" 
         direct="true" 
         class="choose-product-file" 
         data-direct="true" 
         data-as="file" 
         data-url="/attachments/cache/presign" 
         data-presigned="true" 
         data-reference="d105c8c6fd72880c844dc61cb52b0639" 
         accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" 
         type="file" 
         id="product_product_image">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Get the value of input, convert it to JSON, fetch the data

```
let value = $('.btn input:first-child').val();
let data = JSON.parse(value.replace(/'/g, '"'));

// values needed
let id = data.id;
let filename = data.filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `id` and `filename` stored in the value of the first input tag, first get the `JSON.stringify` version of the value, then parse it as `json` and then separately extract the `id` and the `filename` from the `parsed JSON` of the value of the first input tag.

Check my working code snippet below.

---

**Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  this_var = $('input#first').val();
  json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + this_var + ")"));
  json = JSON.parse(json);
  var temp = $('#print').text();
  temp += "id:" + json["id"] + "<br>";
  temp += "filename:" + json["filename"] + "<br>";
  $('#print').html(temp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-file">Choose image
  <input id="first" value="{'id': '55e3385361c84c81c98087907e3f424ff4db6dac412cdcadf40090c04c25',
                'filename': 'firstlogo.png', 
                'content_type':'image/png',
                'size':43393}" 
         data-reference="d105c8c6fd72880c844dc61cb52b0639" 
         type="hidden" 
         name="product[product_image]">
  <input presigned="true" 
         direct="true" 
         class="choose-product-file" 
         data-direct="true" 
         data-as="file" 
         data-url="/attachments/cache/presign" 
         data-presigned="true" 
         data-reference="d105c8c6fd72880c844dc61cb52b0639" 
         accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" 
         type="file" 
         id="product_product_image">
</span>
<div id="print"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assess the span by class and select the child attribute you want.

```
$('.btn').children().last().attr('id');
```

Comment: I need the id and name from the first tag in the curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

This should get the values you are looking for:

```
 $('.btn input').last().data('url')
 $('.btn input').last().attr('id')
```